# Receive SMS on virtual device

Tags: api, simulation

I am in search for a solution that might allow me to receive SMSs on a virtual device through an API service.

I want to send the SMS from a specific phone number using Postman (or other API tool) and receive it on a virtual device (I would prefer Browserstack, but anything else will do), also with a specific phone number.

In Postman I am using a POST call that has the "To:" and "From:" parameters defined in the request body. And it works with real device with SIM in it. I would like to automatize this and use virtual devices.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention if you are looking for something free or paid.

Twilio allows you to [send SMSes](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-send-sms-messages-csharp) with their API and

it  seems that you are able to [receive SMSes](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-receive-and-reply) as an HTTP response.

When I had a look for a project of mine their pricing wasn't that bad.

Comment: It doesn't really matter if it's free or not. I used Twilio too, but I am familiar with Postman and it's also free :). The only problem is that I cannot trigger the SMS on virtual devices, like device farms. Browserstack does not offer this option, I was wondering if maybe you guys know others that might. Couldn't find anything so far.